# How to write a SQL query based on using following input to calculate below output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input:

[image: input]

Output:

[image]

I am trying to write this query in SQL server.

Comment: Use `left join`

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: This question is off-topic for the Stack Overflow platform, and can be closed for several reasons: (1) no prior effort, no research, (2) too broad, (3) no [mcve]. Please **always make a genuine effort before posting**, and then show that effort in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `LEFT JOIN` and do select the fields like shown below,

```
select t.id, tt.tid, ot.oid, pt.pid
from test t
left join test_tid tt on t.id = tt.id
left join test_pid pt on t.id = pt.id
left join test_oid ot on t.id = ot.id
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working after adding group by condition to it. It required due to my data has duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select isnull(isnull(t1.id,t2.id),t3.id),t1.tid,t2.oid,t3.pid
from test_tid t1 full outer join test_oid t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
full outer join test_pid t3
on (t1.id = t3.id)
```